# Как проверить длину присланного сообщения

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Пишу чат-бота в telegram на языке Python 3.10 и aiogram 2.x

Столкнулся с следующей проблемой: когда пользователь присылает в бот сообщение с более чем 4096 символами, то в обработчик, по всей видимости, приходит два апдейта (потому-что следующий код делает два print`а). Вопрос: Как узнать длину сообщения присланного пользователем?

```
@dp.message_handler(state='*')
async def test(message: types.Message):
    print(len(message.text))
```

Comment: Можно для такой отправки сделать отдельный стейт, и при завершении юзер должен написать определенную команду, которая завершит стейт и как-то обработает это сообщение

Answer (score 1):

Выведи в консоль все атрибуты новых сообщений, запусти сервис, отправь то, которое короче 4096, а потом, то, которое длиннее.

Если параметры (исключая message.text) идентичны, то поможет следующее:

Смотреть на длину сообщения каждый раз. У каждого сообщения свой id, и если длина сообщения == 4096, то через время "t" проверять, есть ли следующее по id, а дальше время отправки, оно должно быть минимальным, но каким именно - зависит от интернет-соединения юзера. Так что, с "t" поиграться придётся.

А если нет, то смотри на те параметры, которые отличаются, и ответ ищи там)

Примерный код сниппет:

```
cur_max_len = 4096
sleep_time = 0.5
next_id = 0


@bot.on(events.NewMessage())
async def test(event):
    global next_id
    if len(event.message.text) > cur_max_len:
        next_id = event.message.id + 1
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
        next_message = await bot.get_messages(event.sender, ids=next_id)
        summ_text = event.message.text + next_message[0].text
        
    elif event.message.id == next_id:
        return 
    else:
        pass  # То, что нужно делать обычно
```

Кривовато, но общая суть должна быть понятна.

Естественно, при асинхронной разработке, нельзя хранить в одной переменной id сообщения. Сюда либо БД подключать, либо сделать лист, который нужно будет чистить

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Comment: Поправил ответ.